# regsvr32 fails with GetLastError returns 0x0000007e

Tags: delphi, regsvr32

I'm trying to register a delphi-made library (with dependencies). On first try, regsvr32 failed saying it could not find the specified module, for which I found answer and  copied all dependencies into the same directory my dll resides.

But now, regsvr32 fails with the message `GetLastError returned 0x0000007e.`, and I could not find anywhere what this specific error code means. All mentions I found relate to a specific program or library and how to solve it for that specific reason. Examples:

- [0x0000007e Error When Registering Olemsg32.dll or Cdo.dll Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238265/en-us) (at support.microsoft.com)
- [RegSvr32 Error: 'LoadLibrary ("safileup.dll") failed. GetLastError returns 0x0000007e](http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_213.aspx) (at support.softartisans.com)

The command I use to register is:

```
regsvr32 C:\path\to\library.dll
```

Any idea of what causes this error and how to solve it?

**UPDATE:** Seems that the error code corresponded to ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, and it meant (in a really obscure way) "The specified module could not be found."... same error I had before.

I copied the entire folder of a running instalation into the test machine (instead of trying to make a new instalation) and I was able to register the library. I'll now have to identify which one was the file I was needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only find three definitions for that error code:

```
# for hex 0x7e / decimal 126 :
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED                           bugcodes.h
NMERR_REMOTE_NOT_A_SERVER                                     netmon.h
SQL_126_severity_15                                           sql_err
# Invalid pseudocolumn '%.*ls'.
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h
```

Are you sure the DLL is an ActiveX/COM library that needs to be registered with RegSvr32?

Comment: It is. Actually, I was able to register it in my development machine using the exact same command. But the error occurs when trying to register on a test machine.

Comment: What version of Windows? If Vista or higher, are you running as an Administrator?

Comment: I can register on 7. Problem occurs on XP. Still, I think I resolved it already: seems some dependencies were still missing. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help!