# tdbl5mu.dll failed to register HRESULT

Tags: dll, windows-7, com, win32com

> > while  trying to install my application in 32bit windows7 machine i am getting the error like:
> >
> > "C:\windows\system32\tdbl5mu.dll to register, HRESULT-2147024770 contact your support personnel"
> >      Even i try to install trough command prompt as a administrator right. Still same error I am getting. Any suggestion to  get me out of this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regsvr32 fails with GetLastError returns 0x0000007e](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490508/regsvr32-fails-with-getlasterror-returns-0x0000007e)

Comment: Try to search for HRESULT 0x8007007E. Maybe [Module could not be found HRESULT 0x8007007E](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e) can help you.

Comment: @ Jacob Seleznev: Actually I am using Win7 32 bit. I am trying to register the DLL with administrator rights. Still I am not able to register the DLL. and when i am trying to install my MSI I am getting the Error "Make sure the binary is stored in pacified  path or debug it to check for problem...." I need a solution to fixed it.